# Get XML Node attribute value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an XML

```
<MT5 v="1.0.0">
  <L>
    <PKL>115</PKL>
    <DID>c4c0fee0cb7bc70755d0c996e02431ed6e36f5b0031108</DID>
    <OCD>2014-04-07T17:13:45</OCD>
    <DDT>2014-04-07T17:13:45</DDT>
    <D>
      <PKD o="1">1001</PKD>
      <PKD o="2">1002</PKD>
    </D>
  </L>
</MT5>
```

I need to get value as below
PKL   PKD     O
115   1001    1
115   1002    2

I am using the below query to get data but not getting how to pick the value of 'O'

```
SELECT  @xmldoc2.value('(/MT5/L/PKL)[1]', 'int' ) AS PKL,
   L.PKD.value('.', 'int') AS PKD,
   'Dont konw how to pick value of o' AS O

FROM 
   @xmldoc2.nodes('MT5/L/D/PKD') L(PKD)
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Thanks Antti for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select L.N.value('(PKL/text())[1]', 'int') as PKL,
       P.N.value('text()[1]', 'int') as PKD,
       P.N.value('@o', 'int') as O
from @xmldoc2.nodes('/MT5/L') as L(N)
  cross apply L.N.nodes('D/PKD') as P(N)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16405)

Answer (score 0):

In the following node:

```
<PKD o="2">1002</PKD>
```

"o" is an attribute.  In XPath, you can refer to attributes with an @ sign.  `@o`.  In your complete example, you can pick 'o' by just supplying the attribute refrence to the XML *value* method.

```
SELECT  
  @xmldoc2.value('(/MT5/L/PKL)[1]', 'int' ) AS PKL,
  L.PKD.value('.', 'int') AS PKD,
  L.PKD.value('@o', 'int') AS O,
FROM 
@xmldoc2.nodes('MT5/L/D/PKD') L(PKD)
```